# What do we got?

Tags: american-english, british-english, colloquialisms

***What do we got?***

In vernacular American speech, I have heard this structure several times. A search in COCA yields 36 results for "what do we got" and 107 results for "what do you got". This is what Google Ngram Viewer says about the usage of "what do we got" in its American English corpus:
[image]

And here is a comparison between "what do you got", "what do you have" and "what have you got":
[image]

As you see, by the year 2000, authors were using (the ungrammatical) "what do you got" instead of the other two options on one percent of the occasions, which is not negligible, considering the upward trend in the usage and the fact that the Ngram corpus has a bias against colloquial language.

However, in British English "got" (as a present tense, without have) is never used with "do". Searches for "do we got" and "do you got" in BNC give almost no result. On the other hand you occasionally (or more often?) hear British people say "got to (gotta)" (without "have") in declarative sentences.

My questions about this usage are:

- What is its origin?
- Does it belong to a regional dialect or is it evenly distributed over America?
- Should it be recognized as a (non)standard colloquialism?
- Why is it still not used in the UK *at all*? What is the fundamental difference between *I got to go* and *Do you got to go* ?

P.S. Look at the "bump" over the 40s in the first diagram. Either this is supremely strange, or something's wrong with Ngram Viewer.

Comment: *"Whaddaya got"* is perfectly acceptable in colloquial speech. It's a shortening of *"what have you got"*. The written instances Google books finds are probably from people who have expanded it incorrectly.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I tried, but I should have searched better. Thank you.

Comment: @Farid: I only found it because (a) it was my own question, and (b) I recalled Peter made much the same comment first time around, so I did a Google site-specific search for **"Whaddaya got"**. I'd never have found it using the SE built-in search, even though I'd have known for sure there *was* such a question! :)